# bash one liner to remove duplicate path in line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with lot of a strings and one line starts with `LIBXML2_INCLUDE`

and the file is generated by another program to be specific by ./configure, this line wrongly gives two path and the first path is not correct and i need to remove it. This is how the line appears in file

```
LIBXML2_INCLUDE=-I/home/gan/Music/wvm/build/level/ast/deliveryx/libxml2//home/gan/Music/wvm/build/level/ast/deliveryx/libxml2/include/libxml2
```

i need to remove first `/home/gan/Music/wvm/build/level/ast/deliveryx/libxml2/`
and expected output is

```
LIBXML2_INCLUDE=-I/home/gan/Music/wvm/build/level/ast/deliveryx/libxml2/include/libxml2
```

How can i create a bash one liner to accomplish this?

Comment: This sound like you have an issue with [Autotools's `automake`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html) or the directives in `Makefile.in` with multiple sources for the libxml2's headers.

Comment: @LéaGris indeed but i am unable to identify hows its coming so i went for this one liner

Comment: Did you try with `./configure --with-libxml2=/home/gan/Music/wvm/build/level/ast/deliveryx/libxml2/include/libxml2`

Comment: @LéaGris the configure command looks like this ./configure CC="/opt/i586-linux-gcc -m32 -march=i586 --sysroot=/opt/sysroots/i586-linux" 
CFLAGS="-I/home/gan/Music/wvm/build/level/ast/deliveryx/libxml2/include/libxml2 -pipe -feliminate-unused-debug-types -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable" --target=i586-linux --host=i586-linux --build=i686-linux --with-libxml2=/home/gan/Music/wvm/build/level/ast/deliveryx/libxml2/include/libxml2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
# cat file
SOMEVAR=-I/some/path//some/path
# sed -i -e '/^SOMEVAR=/s,=-I.*//,=-I/,' file
# cat file
SOMEVAR=-I/some/path
#
```

To be a bit more fancy --

```
$ cat file
SOMEVAR=-I/some/path//some/path
$ sed -i -e '/^SOMEVAR=/s,=-I\(.*\)/\1$,=-I\1/,' file
$ cat file
SOMEVAR=-I/some/path/
$
```